# Count number of rows containing string per index using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set like this:

```
index sentence
1     bobby went to the gym
1     sally the bad
1     days are good
2     sunny side up
2     the weird
```

I want to count how many times 'the' appears in the columns 'sentence' by index:

```
index count_the 
1     2
2     1
```

how would I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index' :[1,1,1,2,2],'sentence':['bobby went to the gym','sally the bad','days are good','sunny side up','the weird']})
df['counts'] = df['sentence'].str.count('the')
print(df.groupby('index')['counts'].sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

First `groupby.Series.apply`, then use `series.str.count`:

```
df = df.groupby('index').sentence.apply(' '.join).reset_index()

print(df)
   index                                           sentence
0      1  bobby went to the gym sally the bad days are good
1      2                            sunny side up the weird

df['count_the'] = df.sentence.str.count('the')

print(df.drop(['sentence'],axis=1))
   index  count_the
0      1          2
1      2          1
```

Answer (score 1):

one way from `findall` , notice I treat the index columns as index here

```
df.sentence.str.findall(r'\bthe\b').str.len().sum(level=0)
Out[363]: 
index
1    2
2    1
Name: sentence, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Upvote - though it is not the straight forward answer but it did solve my problem where I was searching a regex instead of a constant string and IMHO the `.sum(level=0)` is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use groupby()+ apply():

```
df.groupby('index').apply(lambda x: x['sentence'].str.contains(r'.*the').sum()).reset_index(name = 'count_the')
```

or groupby()+ apply():

```
df.groupby('index').agg({'sentence': lambda x: x.str.contains(r'.*the').sum()}).reset_index(name = 'count_the')
```